# requestLocation() does not ask for permission even though "Ask next time" is ticked

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have a variable `var locationManager: CLLocationManager`.

During the runtime of the app, I want to ask for a one-time location with
`locationManager.requestLocation()`.

However when I do so, the delegate almost immediately informs me with
`locationManager(manager:didFailWithError:)`
Even though in my security settings, Location is set as "Ask next Time".

When I set the setting to "Always", i receive a proper location update, but I don't want the user to explicitly activate them in the settings.
How can I make my App ask for permission?

Edit: Usage Descriptions are properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestlocation` gets a one-time location and avoids the energy impact of continuous location updates where only a single location update is required, but it does not prompt the user for location permission.

If your authorisation state is `.notDetermined` you need to call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and receive an authorisation callback with a positive result before you can call `requestLocation`.